# accessing return object after restoring purchase (ios)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, swift2, ios9, restore

I have 12 items each with purchase button and one "restore purchase" button. When user touches restore purchase button, it calls "restorePurchased": `restoreLabel.addTarget(self, action: "restorePurchased:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`

In restorePurchased function

```
 func restorePurchased(sender:AnyObject) {

    loadingBg.hidden = false

    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()

    print("purchased product: \(gv.purchasedProduct)")

    if(gv.purchasedProduct == "02") {
        gv.sharedDefaults.setBool(true , forKey: "purchased_02")
    } else if(gv.purchasedProduct == "03") {
        gv.sharedDefaults.setBool(true , forKey: "purchased_03")
    } else if(gv.purchasedProduct == "04") {
        gv.sharedDefaults.setBool(true , forKey: "purchased_04")
    } else if(gv.purchasedProduct == "05") {
        gv.sharedDefaults.setBool(true , forKey: "purchased_05")
    } else if(gv.purchasedProduct == "06") {
        gv.sharedDefaults.setBool(true , forKey: "purchased_06")
    } else if(gv.purchasedProduct == "07") {
        gv.sharedDefaults.setBool(true , forKey: "purchased_07")
    } else if(gv.purchasedProduct == "08") {
        gv.sharedDefaults.setBool(true , forKey: "purchased_08")
    } else if(gv.purchasedProduct == "09") {
        gv.sharedDefaults.setBool(true , forKey: "purchased_09")
    } else if(gv.purchasedProduct == "10") { // V3
        gv.sharedDefaults.setBool(true , forKey: "purchased_10")
    } else if(gv.purchasedProduct == "11") {
        gv.sharedDefaults.setBool(true , forKey: "purchased_12")
    } else if(gv.purchasedProduct == "12") { // V4
        gv.sharedDefaults.setBool(true , forKey: "purchased_13")
    } else if(gv.purchasedProduct == "13") { // V4
        gv.sharedDefaults.setBool(true , forKey: "purchased_14")
    }

    gv.purchasedProduct = ""
    gv.sharedDefaults.synchronize()
    disablePurchasedProducts()
    self.restoreCompletedTransactions()
}
```

I am calling restoreCompletedTransaction method and then trying to access returned object so that I can set sharedDefaults(global variable) to true and then synchronize then call disablePurchasedProducts function which changes text of button with each item from "$2.99" to "purchased"

How can I access the returned object or array from restoreCompletedTransactions()?

Thanks in advance for your kind advises.

Comment: You need to read the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267) in the docs to see the proper way to write the code to process restored purchases.